# How can I verify that overall a site is faster after compression has been switched on?

Tags: iis-7, dynamic, compression, gzip

I have suggested that we Enable dynamic content compression on IIS7 to improve user experience. The QA department wants me to demonstrate that it is in fact faster. I've been using Firebug to view the load time waterfall chart generated under the Net setting and it is inconsistent with the overall (total) page load time from page to page. i.e. sometimes faster but sometimes slower.

Dynamic pages by themselves are always faster but now some static uncompressed content appears to be slower.

What I would like is a tool (Firefox addin) that can add together all page load times during a typical workflow (usage) of a site and give me a final time figure. I would then use that with dynamic compression enabled and disabled to see what the total net effect is. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fiddler from Microsoft, it has a much low level interaction with Explorer and could be easily used to produce comparative graphics.

Firebug is very useful for a lot of stuff, but for every kind of measurement that involves network Fiddler is much better because instead of examining the page it works as a local proxy and so can examine the network traffic much better.

Site link: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 2):

The Net tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) gives you timings for every item the browser downloads. There's also an option to disable the cache, to guarantee accurate timings. I believe that by default it will clear the timings after every page load, but that can be disabled.